# Messaging sendEmail Issue

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

I'm using a single email message to send an email. When we tried to sent an email with a wrong email address on newly created lead record.
I'm getting message result success is true. But the same record I have tried to send an email in the second time, I'm getting message result success is false.
Please advice on this.

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMassEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses(toEmail);
email.setTargetObjectId(lstcountLead.id);
email.setTemplateId(templateId);
email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
lstMassEmails.add(email); 
Map<Id,Messaging.SendEmailResult> maptargetToResult = new Map<Id,Messaging.SendEmailResult>();
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> sendEmailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(lstMassEmails,false);
Integer i=0; 
for(Messaging.SendEmailResult sendEmailResult: sendEmailResults){
    maptargetToResult.put(lstMassEmails.get(i).getTargetObjectId(),sendEmailResult);    
    i++;
}
System.debug('!!!maptargetToResult'+maptargetToResult);(First Time)
!!!maptargetToResult{00Qp00000050eh9EAA=Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=();isSuccess=true;]}
System.debug('!!!maptargetToResult'+maptargetToResult);(Second Time)
!!!maptargetToResult{00Qp00000050eh9EAA=Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=(Messaging.SendEmailError
[getMessage=The target object email address is currently marked as bounced.;getStatusCode=EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED;getTargetObjectId=00Qp00000050eh9EAA;]);
isSuccess=false;]}
```

Comment: Have you read the message?  Do you know what a bounced email is?

Comment: If I send an email to an invalid email address, I know that it will get bounced. I should have got the error in my first attempt itself. But, for the first attempt, it returns success as true. When i repeat the same, im getting bounced error. Would like to know why this happens?